# What is the difference between html and htmls

Tags: html

I'm wrote this site for work with `HTML` and `PHP` and I'm being told it needs to be `htmls` not `html`.  What does this mean?  What is the difference between the two?

Thanks

Comment: Are you certain they didn't mean https vs http?

Comment: One is singular, and the other is plural.

Comment: they said verbatim "Number one priority is make sure the website is `htmls` not `html`"  He probably meant `https`

Comment: I've found a reference to a Windows "server-side HTML" file called HTMLS, but in over 20 years in IT I've never actually run across it. as others said, he probably means HTTPS. maybe better politely ask the necktie who told you this what the heck he's talking about.

Comment: Not to badmouth your client (this is my own experience talking), but a lot of times clients know there's "something important you need to do" but always seem to muck up the jargon. $20 says it's https.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they meant HTTPS then you will need to set up your server to use SSL. Simply put, HTTPS is different from HTTP as it encrypts the communications between the server and connecting clients. It is generally used to transmit confidential data that you want to protect. A good starting point on information is here:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Secure. It is set up on the server so you will want to google "How to set up HTTPs on ? " Where ? is your server.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure HTMLS is a viable/existent technology. Perhaps they meant HTTPS/SSL?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure its HTMLS and not SHTML?  SHTML - the S stands for "Server-side include".

Answer (score -1):

Html is a package that by it we can draw a fantastic web or we can develop our web page as useful for customers of the internet web pages.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).